# How does ChunkedInputStream work internally with Apache HttpClient 4.x?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I am bit new to Apache HC API. I am trying to download huge file from server `(10 GB) on cloud environment` and then I have to upload on to Amazon S3.

As file is too big, it comes up with `transfer encoding as chunked` and `gzip format`. Cloud env neither have enough disk space to store this file as temp file nor such file can be accommodated in memory.

Mainly I have 2 interfaces,

```
ResourceDownloader {
  InputStream download(AbstractChannel channel);
 }

ResourceUploader{
   void upload(AbstractChannel channel, InputStream inputStream);
}
```

**Part1:**

While using Apache  Httpclient lib, I am seeing return http response with following structure,

> ```
> ResponseEntityProxy contains >> {
>  - BasicHttpEntity [WrappedEntity]
>  - content as ChunkeInputStream
> }
> ```

So does this response mean whole 10GB would be available in memory byte buffer at client side after completion of client.execute(getMethod) call?

Or is it like as soon as I invoke call to read as below, it would get chunks from server?
[In real case, disk would not be available , but below is just for demo]

```
  try {
        FileOutputStream fos = (FileOutputStream) outputStream;

        if(inputStream instanceof GZIPInputStream) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            //close resources
            fos.close();
            inputStream.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Exception occurred while processing file on disk", e);
    }
```

**Part2:**

I know multi part upload if I have content length or full file available, but in case of chunked input stream, how should we upload it to Amazon S3?

Thanks,
Dharam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpClient always streams request and response entities unless specifically instructed to do otherwise.